# Form Redirect not working if 'destination' is in URL

Tags: 7, forms, redirection

In one of my forms, I'm trying to set a `$form_state['redirect']` so the form will go to that destination after the user clicks one of the action buttons.

If I inspect `$form_state['redirect']` both before and after I add the redirect, it is NULL before, and after contains the proper array. Here's how I'm setting up the redirect:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'my/custom/path/' . $nid,
  array('query' => drupal_get_destination()),
);
```

I want to preserve the destination from the form that the user's viewing to the next path (that's why I'm calling `drupal_get_destination()`, which returns an array with `'destination' => 'some/path/here'` inside.

It seems that, because there's already a destination in the path of the current form, the form redirects to that destination no matter what I put in my own form submit handler (see above code). I even tried using drupal_goto() and that didn't redirect the user either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When a form is processed, the value of `$form_state['redirect']` is sent to [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto), and `drupal_goto()` always favors `$_GET['destination']` over its own `$path` parameter.

For the sake of completeness, in Drupal 6, you were somewhat out of luck without setting your own headers in [`hook_exit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_exit/6):

```
function mymodule_exit($destination = NULL) {
  $my_destination = 'foo/bar';
  header('Location: ' . url($my_destination));
  exit;
}
```

In Drupal 7, [`hook_drupal_goto_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_drupal_goto_alter/7) was added for this specific use case:

```
function mymodule_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  $path = 'foo/bar';
}
```

Another option for Drupal 7, which is closer to what you want to do, is to reset the static cache for [`drupal_get_destination()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7)  in your submit handler using [`drupal_static_reset()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static_reset/7):

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // See note
  $form_state['redirect'][] = drupal_get_destination();
  $form_state['redirect'][] = 'foo/bar';

  unset($_GET['destination']);
  drupal_static_reset('drupal_get_destination');
  drupal_get_destination();
}
```

Since you call `drupal_get_destination()` immediately after the reset, Drupal is blissfully unaware of the destination parameter for the rest of the page build, including when it calls `drupal_goto()`.

**Note:** I changed the code for defining `$form_state['redirect']` because you never want to overwrite the variable: other submit handlers might've defined their own redirects. Drupal will always use the *last* item in the array, so if you want `foo/bar` to override the destination parameter (and every other redirect defined up to that point), it needs to be last.

Comment: Perfect, and very good explanation. I actually found a little more by working through the flow of a processed form - drupal_goto() is ultimately the reason my simple 'redirect' wasn't working. I needed to overwrite $_GET['destination'] too.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for this, but for some reason this didn't work when I tried it.  I got a fatal error -- the data sent in the example answer above doesn't satisfy the requirements of `drupal_goto()`

It may be because this answer is rather old, but I was able to get it work with this instead:

```
function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {


  $form_state['redirect'] = array(
    'foo/bar', array(
      'query' => drupal_get_destination()
    )
  );

  unset($_GET['destination']);
  drupal_static_reset('drupal_get_destination');
  drupal_get_destination();

}
```

I know this violates this note:

> you never want to overwrite the variable: other submit handlers
>   might've defined their own redirects.

But, in this case, you do definitely want to overwrite the variable.  You wouldn't be setting this value unless you wanted to disregard other module's set values.  Also, I think you have to because of the way `drupal_goto()` works with the query parameter.  This may also be why the original answer was throwing fatal errors on my site.

Comment: This answer helped me realize that in some circumstances, you may want to completely override the `$form_state['redirect']`, or you may get a WSOD with competing redirects.

Answer (score -2):

set form **#action**

```
global $base_path;
$form['#action'] = $base_path . '/node/'.$form_state['node']->nid.'/mytab';
```

Comment: -1 I think calling `drupal_goto()` in `hook_node_insert()` will screw things up (because `drupal_goto()` calls `drupal_exit()` preventing the new node from being saved).

Comment: true - in a node_insert hook .. (edited the answer)

Comment: This doesn't issue a redirect as OP asked, but submits the form to a different path.