# User Register page is different if there is a destination parameter in the url

Tags: users, uri

I'm trying to find where to go in Drupal to find out how a user register form is displayed.

If the url is user/register, a person is routed to a standard registration form.

However, if the url is user/register?destination=voucher, then that person is routed to a user registration form that mimics our popup modal registration form, however, is not in a popup. This is not the regular registration form.

I want to find where this is set so that if a destination parameter is in the url, to go to the standard registration form.

Answer (score 1):

The `drupal_get_form()` returns a form array for rendering. In your case `drupal_get_form('user_register_form')`. You can use `drupal_render()` with the result to render the html output.

If you need to override the form, use `hook_form_alter()` and change the `$form_state['redirect'][] = 'your/redirect/path'`. Also try removing the destination param with `unset($_GET['destination'])`.

Here are some references:

- [Form Redirect not working if 'destination' is in URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/form-redirect-not-working-if-destination-is-in-url-drupal-7)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175687/redirect-after-registration-in-drupal
- http://www.brianvuyk.com/story-type/changing-redirect-value-drupal-node-form-d6

Comment: I found where that is called.  In user.module in the user_menu function there is this:  

`
  $items['user/register'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create new account',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_register_form'),
    'access callback' => 'user_register_access',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
`
  
How do I get it to recognize user/register?destination=tester or anything after register?

Comment: I tried $items['user/register%'] but it still gives me that other registration page, the default registration page.

Comment: I also tried $items['%user/register'] and I get an access denied for both paths, user/register and user/register?destination=tester

Comment: I also tried I['user/%register'] and I get an access denied for both paths, user/register and user/register?destination=tester

Comment: If I force drupal_deliver_html_page function to recognize that user/register?destination=**** should be user/register, it goes to the right page, I just need it to render the content of user/register.

I hacked this in common.inc drupal_deliver_html_page.

Comment: Here is what I've done so far, but am open to a better solution:  I hacked the core file common.inc in the function drupal_deliver_html_page.  At the top of the function, I added this which routes it to the correct form, but does not include last minute form weight adjustments:

$current_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($current_url,"user/register?destination=")>-1) {$page_callback_result=drupal_get_form('user_register_form');}

Comment: Don't hack core... You can get the 'destination' param with drupal_get_destination(). But Rules is probably a best fit for your needs. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is write a very small custom module. I'd assume you know the ID of your custom register form, so replace the value of `$id_of_custom_register_form` variable with the id of your custom register form on function `custom_module_register_page()`. Here's the code:

custom_module.info:

```
name = "Custom Module"
description = "Custom Module alters user/register menu"
dependencies[] = user
core = "7.x"
package = "Other"
```

custom_module.module:

```
/**
 * Implementation of HOOK_menu_alter()
 */
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Change the function that returns the page content with
  // our custom function that checks the destination parameter
  // and return the appropriate form
  $items['user/register']['page callback'] = '_custom_module_register_page';

  // Empty the arguments array
  $items['user/register']['page arguments'] = array();
}

/**
 * Custom page callback for user/register path
 */
function _custom_module_register_page() {
  $id_of_custom_register_form = 'id_of_my_custom_register_form';  

  // If destination is set return $id_of_my_custom_register_form form
  if(isset($_GET['destination'])) {
    $form_id = $id_of_my_custom_register_form;
  }
  // Otherwise return normal register form
  else {
    $form_id = 'user_register_form';
  }

  return drupal_get_form($form);
}
```