# Programmatically redirect

Tags: users, rules, redirection, taxonomy-terms

I'm creating an action to trigger on a rule when a user is logged in. I have a field of the user that is a term reference.

I would like to redirect to the url field of the chosen term. This is how I get the chosen url:

```
$tid = $user->field_redirect_field['und'][0]['tid'];
$taxonomy = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$url = $taxonomy->field_url['und'][0]['safe_value'];
```

I receive a perfect url like **stocklijst/gezocht** (this works ok). Now I would like to redirect to that url. I've tried this:

```
drupal_goto($url);
```

But it doesn't redirect. It always goes to the front-page...

**UPDATE:**

This is what I do now:

I have a rule (When user logged in) that triggers a custom action "Redirect to user url". It's a custom action like this:

```
function redirectonlogin_rules_action_info() {
    $actions = array(
        'redirectonlogin_redirect_login' => array(
            'label' => t('Redirect on login'),
            'group' => t('My custom actions'),
            'parameter' => array(
                // curent user
                'user' => array(
                    'type' => 'user',
                    'label' => t('User'),
                    'description' => t('The current logged in user.'),
                    'save' => FALSE,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $actions;
}

function redirectonlogin_redirect_login($user) {
    // REDIRECT TO USER REDIRECT FIELD
    $tid = $user->field_redirect_field['und'][0]['tid'];
    $taxonomy = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    $url = $taxonomy->field_url['und'][0]['safe_value'];

    unset($_GET['destination']);
    drupal_static_reset('drupal_get_destination');
    drupal_goto($url);
}
```

The user can select a url in a select list. These are taxonomy terms... .

This works perfectly. But it takes some time, could there be a cleaner way and faster way of doing this?

Comment: Look at this -> http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/form-redirect-not-working-if-destination-is-in-url-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks for the information, it works, but a bit slow. Could there be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you could use hook_user_login(&edit, $account). This hook runs after a user logs in and isn't dependent on the Rules module:

```
function redirectonlogin_redirect_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($account->field_redirect_field['und'][0]['tid']);

  // These 2 lines may not be required depending on your set up.
  unset($_GET['destination']);
  drupal_static_reset('drupal_get_destination');

  $edit['redirect'] = $term->field_url['und'][0]['safe_value'];
}
```

But if something is interfering, like a drupal_goto() in another module that forces a redirect to the normal landing, you might need to replace:

$edit['redirect'] = $term->field_url['und'][0]['safe_value'];

with:

drupal_goto($term->field_url['und'][0]['safe_value']);

drupal_goto() forces a redirect and will ignore anything that comes after it in the page request.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)(),
In this hook we could redirect with `$form['redirect'] = $url;`

Comment: The login form? But I need data from the user ... And he's not logged in yet. It's not possible I think?

Comment: Hi, you could load user value from user input. From user name, user mail