# How to override VBO redirect after performed action?

Tags: 7, redirection, views

My problem is that I can't override the URL where VBO redirects me to after I performed a default action. When I write my own actions I simply put `$_GET['destination'] = 'my/target';` inside my custom form submit and that works. I tried to alter VBO's form submit to attach my own submit but that doesn't work:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_bulk_operations_form') {
    array_push($form['#submit'], 'MYMODULE_vbo_redirect');
  };
}

function MYMODULE_vbo_redirect() {
  $_GET['destination'] = 'my/target';
}
```

When I testhack the VBO module and inside `views_bulk_operations_form_submit($form, &$form_state)` replace the final redirect with my custom one, it works. How can I get inside there and get my custom redirect executed without hacking?

Comment: This shouldn't be different for VBO forms, I think the accepted answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/form-redirect-not-working-if-destination-is-in-url-drupal-7) is the sort of thing you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to alter the wrong form. VBO somehow merges its form stuff with the views form itself. So I had to look there to attach my custom submit. Then I had to pay attention to attach it in the same moment the `views_bulk_operations_form_submit` is attached. Then I set the cancel button to also bring me back where I want. And finally set `$form_state['redirect']` in my attached submit.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_form_MYVIEW_page') {
    $form['#action'] = '/my/target'; // the url that is displayed when in VBO multistep

    if (!empty($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'])) {

      if (in_array('views_bulk_operations_form_submit', $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'])) {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_vbo_redirect';
        $form['actions']['cancel']['#href'] = 'my/target';
        $form['actions']['cancel']['#options']['path'] = 'my/target';
        dpm($form);
      }
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_vbo_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('my/target');
}
```

Only problem left is that this redirect always gets triggered when performing any VBO action from this view. But I can live with that for now.

Comment: this is just excellent :)

Answer (score 1):

Has for VBO, there is a hook dedicated for form alter: `hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $vbo)`

Example (modifying the email action):

```
function YOURMODULE_views_bulk_operations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $vbo) {
  $form_id = $form['#form_id'];
  if ($form_state['step'] == 'views_form_views_form') {
    // Alter the first step of the VBO form (the selection page).
  }
  elseif ($form_state['step'] == 'views_bulk_operations_config_form') {
    // Alter the configuration step of the VBO form.
    if( $form_id == 'views_form_YOURVIEWSMACHINENAME_YOURVIEWSDISPLAY' ) {
      if(isset($form['recipient'])) {
        $form['recipient']['#default_value'] = '[user:mail]';
      }
      $form['message']['#type'] = 'text_format'; //> sends an array...
      $form['message']['#default_value'] = variable_get('NAMEOFAVAR');
      //add token list
      $form['token'] = array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => t('Replacement tokens'),
          '#collapsible' => TRUE,
          '#collapsed' => TRUE,
      );
      $token_types = array('user');
      $form['token']['tokens'] = array(
          '#markup' => theme('token_tree', array('token_types' => $token_types))
      );
    }
  }
  elseif ($form_state['step'] == 'views_bulk_operations_confirm_form') {
    // Alter the confirmation step of the VBO form.
    array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'YOURMODULE_sendmail_vbo_submit');
    $form_state['operation']->formOptions['message'] = $form_state['operation']->formOptions['message']['value'];
  }
}
```

The only thing to notice is that in your custom submit function, you don't get the form_state values has usual. I must dig more to find how to get them.

EDIT:
To alter/save/do stuff with `$form_state['values']`, better to put your custom submit or validate function in the second "if":

```
elseif ($form_state['step'] == 'views_bulk_operations_config_form') {
      $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'YOURMODULE_sendmail_vbo_validate';
}
```

Comment: Be aware my code is work in progress, don't just rely on it... Must need some more "if" to be perfect... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use `hook_drupal_goto_alter`, for example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drupal_goto_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  if (CONDITION) {
    $path = 'my/target';
  }
}
```

Where in CONDITION you can check for the specific desired path which you want to override by checking the value of `current_path()` or `arg()`.

Not ideal, but it's simpler than implementing custom submit handler (e.g. in `$form['select']['action::views_bulk_operations_argument_selector_action']['#submit']`) using `hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter` and finding the right place to override the path.

Answer (score -1):

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
 if ($form_id == 'views_bulk_operations_form') {
$form['#submit']='MYMODULE_vbo_redirect';
}
}
function MYMODULE_vbo_redirect() {
// Use die('here') and submit the form.if it dies then redirect it 
drupal_goto('my/target');
}
```

Hope this will helps you

Comment: I think `drupal_goto()` is no good idea here. It stops the whole VBO process before performing any action.